# Is it possible to use HTTPS/SSL on GitHub Pages sites with a custom domain?

Tags: ssl, github, github-pages

Is there any way to use HTTPS/SSL on GitHub Pages sites that use a custom domain? SSL is recommended for better search engine ranking and there are a lot of other uses for it beyond that.

Comment: You'd need to set up a proxy server somewhere to handle it, so this is likely off-topic for SO. [Here](https://blog.jeaye.com/2016/03/01/github-pages-https/) is an example.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Custom domains on GitHub Pages **do** support HTTPS / SSL:

> GitHub Pages has supported custom domains since 2009, and sites on the `*.github.io` domain have supported HTTPS since 2016. Today, custom domains on GitHub Pages are gaining support for HTTPS as well, meaning over a million GitHub Pages sites will be served over HTTPS.
>
> https://blog.github.com/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/

1. Go to `https://github.com/**username**/**repo**/settings`
2. Check the checkbox "Enforce HTTPS":

[image: Enforce HTTPS]

---

Prior to May 1, 2018, SSL was supported by GitHub Pages only on sites using a `*.github.io` domain: https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer after Github added support for custom domains on May 1st, 2018.

Comment: For a simple site like my portfolio will I be ok with HTTP domain on Github pages?

Comment: @NetEmmanuel Yes for sure it will be okay.  It can also support unlimited traffic if your site goes viarl.

Comment: If anyone is facing issues while configuring the new A records for SSL/HTTPS, you can refer to this post that I wrote - https://medium.com/@goelanirudh/add-https-to-your-namecheap-domain-hosted-on-github-pages-d66fd96308b5.

Comment: I really don’t understand. Neither you nor the docs say how to use your domain certificate with a custom domain and my GitHub pages site says don’t trust this page. It makes no sense. Shouldn’t there be a form to add my cert? It doesn’t help that they tell me they use Let’s Encrypt if they don’t tell me how to use them with GitHub Pages.

Comment: Thank you pretty much! You are cool Man :-) You have pointed out at that info and inspired me by that answer)

Answer (score 6):

It's now possible to use HTTPS on GitHub Pages sites with a custom domain

> If you are using `CNAME` or `ALIAS` records for your custom domain, **you’re all set and your site should be accessible over HTTPS**.

> If you are using `A` records, **you must update your site’s DNS records with new IP addresses**. Please see our [guide to setting up your custom domain with Pages and update any A records you might have set](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/).

Once you have HTTPS working:

> You can optionally [“Enforce HTTPS” for your domain](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/) in your repository’s settings, ensuring users who request your site over HTTP are upgraded to HTTPS.

[image: Enforce HTTPS repository configuration]

You can read the full announcement here: https://blog.github.com/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/

Comment: @NetEmmanuel If adding HTTPS support costs you nothing you should definitely add it. You can find more details on why to consider HTTPS support even for static content sites here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142496/which-security-measures-make-sense-for-a-static-web-site.

Comment: I really don’t understand. Neither you nor the docs say how to use your domain certificate with a custom domain and my GitHub pages site says don’t trust this page. It makes no sense. Shouldn’t there be a form to add my cert? It doesn’t help to know they use Let’s Encrypt if they don’t tell me what to do with them.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177720/16087088

Adding to this answer (since I have to go through some other issue - Can't Enforce HTTPS)

- Try removing A record "parked" from your DNS record and other records which could possibly affect the pointing to your GitHub active page.
- Confirm that you have put all the A names from GitHub (probably 185.199.108.153 is for enforcing the https) - [Screenshot of IPs]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8sMM.png
- also add [Your username].github.io in CNAME.
- add "www" in name and [your domain].com as value

Comment: This is the actual answer as updated and works on 2023 Sept. Why it have zero votes?