# HTTPS for a Github pages custom domain with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, github-pages

I have decided to switch to HTTPS for my Github pages custom domain, to do so I have followed [this](http://strd6.com/2016/02/github-pages-custom-domain-with-ssltls/) tutorial step by step. Namely:

- Requested for an SSL in AWS Certificate Manager
- Created a CloudFront distribution
- Changed my DNS A Record to an alias to that distribution

But for some reason, when accessing [christopherkade.com](http://christopherkade.com) the URL follows the default root object I have set in the distribution (christopherkade.com/index.html) and Firefox gives me the following error `The page isn’t redirecting properly` and Chrome `christopherkade.com redirected you too many times.`.

Here are my DNS records:

[image]

My page is hosted on [this](https://github.com/christopherkade/christopherkade.github.io) repository.

Did I forget something?

Comment: How long have you waited? DNS records can take hours to propagate in the worst case. I can see the website fine, but I do not get HTTPS by default.

Comment: I have changed my A record to its default value (that's why it's back to HTTP) while I find a solution. AWS DNS changes should take 60 seconds to propagate, so the problem is not there I believe.

Comment: custom domains on GitHub Pages now allow HTTPS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172216/is-it-possible-to-use-https-ssl-on-github-pages-sites-with-a-custom-domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but it required a change in the service used to deliver HTTPS. I sum it up [here](https://christopherkade.com/blog/ssh-githubpages), but in short:

I now use **Cloudflare** as my DNS and changed my nameservers on AWS Route 53 to the ones given by Cloudflare after setting up my website.

As you can see [christopherkade.com](http://christopherkade.com) is now served in HTTPS.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. Sadly, your link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I have fixed it :)

Comment: For reference, the reason that CloudFront behaves differently is that it doesn't pass through the origin Host header in the request to GitHub. So CloudFront requests christopherkade.github.io, and GitHub issues a redirect to christopherkade.com, which Cloudfront serves, resulting in a redirect loop. Cloudflare passes the request Host header so GitHub is happy.